# image blur css property not working in android- cordova

Tags: android, css, cordova

blurring  images using below css properties:

```
-webkit-filter: blur(50px);
  -moz-filter: blur(50px);
  -o-filter: blur(50px);
  -ms-filter: blur(50px);
```

It working fine on browser but using cordova image is not blurring, checked on android it is not working.
What is the problem?

Comment: which OS is installed ? I mean version

Comment: CSS Blur property is not supported on 4.1 and 4.3

Comment: @Murtaza 4.1.1 i am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method of applying filter effects like  **(blur, grayscale, brightness, contrast and hue)**
are not supported on `Android 4.1` and `4.3`

More CSS properties which are not supported on Android 4.1 and 4.3 are

1. CSS3 Text-shadow
2. CSS Filter Effects (blur, grayscale, brightness,
   contrast and hue)
3. SVG filters (color manipulation)

[Source](http://caniuse.com/#search=blur)

Comment: are you sure? refrence

Comment: Thanks a lot murtaza Hussain. You are right same property worked on android 4.4.4. Jaza'kllah

Comment: can u tell its alternate if possible?

Comment: you can use modernizr.com as an alternative, as the last resort you have to put already blurred image and replace it on unsupported android versions